# Error in adding figure to Latex file: Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex

I tried to use the other answers for thses kind of errors but that couldn't help me. This is a simple part of the code in TexLive.
Error:

```
Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
libpng error: Not a PNG file
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert} % norm: double vertical bars
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {c:/Users/Amin/Desktop/} }

\begin{document}

\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont

\includegraphics{Drawing1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. I assume `Drawing1` is a PNG file? Have you tried with other PNG files?

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT.; yes, that is the name of the file and in PNG format.

Comment: You didn't answer my other question though: have you tried with other PNG files?

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. Just now, it is solved; its related to the PNG file as you correctly guessed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was apparently caused by a corrupt PNG-file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably adding the extension to figure will work.
Just replace
\includegraphics{Drawing1}

by

\includegraphics{Drawing1.png}

Comment: No, LaTeX finds the picture without the file extension. It is a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the name of your figure,

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.85]{test.jpg}
\caption{test}
\label{fig:test_figure}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

this how I did

Comment: Using `[H]` makes using a float a bit pointless. Also, the `center` environment adds additional vertical space. The file ending should not be given, LaTeX picks on on its own.